# Calcular subtotales por categorías en un json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

me encuentro realizando un calculo en Java Script que me de como resultado todo el stock que hay en los diferentes almacenes. Esta es mi data:

```
const data = [
  {ciudad: "Bogotá", name: "Guitarra", value: 2 },
  {ciudad: "Medellin", name: "Piano", value: 124 },
  {ciudad: "Bogotá", name: "Piano", value: 13 },
  {ciudad: "Medellin", name: "Guitarra", value: 56 },
];
```

Quiero clasificar por instrumento y por ciudad para saber cuántos elementos existen en stock.
Os muestro un Ejemplo:

```
const newData = [
  {ciudad: "Bogotá", name: "Guitarra", value: 15 },
  {ciudad: "Medellin", name: "Piano", value: 180 },
];
```

Lo estoy trabajando en React y estoy implementando un filter y un reduce. Aún no logro que funcione como espero:

```
let newData = await data.filter(item => item.name === 'Guitarra' && item.ciudad === 'Bogotá')
```

Eso funciona pero no me estructura la data como quiero. Por eso lo intenté con un reducer.
Para concluir lo que quiero es obtener el ejemplo de la newData para mostrar en un grafico.

Construí esta reduce:

```
let totalGuitarra = data.reduce((total, item) => total + (item.name === 'Guitarra' && item.ciudad === 'Bogotá' ? item.value : 0), 0)
    + data.reduce((total, item) => total + (item.name === 'Medellin' ? item.value : 0), 0)
```

pero me trae valor por valor y al final crearía un json y lo mostraría.
Pero esa no es la intención. Un gráfico va a mostrar: Guitarra=(56 + 2), Piano=(124 + 13) representado en una torta

Comment: Lo que pasa es que según tu estructura, no tienes 13 y 2 en bogota piano, tienes 2 en bogotá guitarra y 2 en bogotá piano, entonces nunca va a funcionar la suma, entonces debes definir bien que es lo que deseas sumar. O aclarar el planteo. Sumar los valores es sencillo, pero hay que saber bien que valores deseas sumar. Revisa tu ejemplo por favor.

Comment: El problema aquí que veo es que no tienes definido como lo quieres agrupar, ya que las sumas que arrojas en tu ejemplo de resultado no coinciden con los valores proporcionados en los datos. Coinciden en cuanto a la ciudad pero no a los productos.

Comment: Si bien quiero que se sumen los value, los quiero clasificar por name y ciudad

Comment: Bueno lo quiero agrupar por name, es decir instrumento para saber el stock actual general que existe, así no se tenga en cuenta la ciudad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en esto:

```
const data = [
  {ciudad: "Bogotá", name: "Guitarra", value: 2 },
  {ciudad: "Medellin", name: "Piano", value: 124 },
  {ciudad: "Bogotá", name: "Piano", value: 13 },
  {ciudad: "Medellin", name: "Guitarra", value: 56 },
];
```

---

Cantidad de un mismo instrumento sin importar lugar:

```
data.filter((item)=>item.name==="Guitarra").reduce((a,b)=>{ return a.value + b.value})
```

Devuelve 58 (Cantidad total de Guitarras, 2 en Bogotá y 56 en Medellín)

---

Cantidad de instrumentos en una misma ciudad (diferentes instrumentos)

```
data.filter((item)=>item.ciudad==="Bogotá").reduce((a,b)=>{ return a.value + b.value})
```

Devuelve 15 (2 pianos y 13 guitarras.)

---

Cantidad por instrumento y ciudad:

```
data.filter((item)=>item.name==="Guitarra" && item.ciudad === "Medellin").reduce((a,b)=>{ return a.value + b.value})
```

Devuelve:

```
{ciudad: 'Medellin', name: 'Guitarra', value: 56}
```

Comment: El inconveniente es que me devuelve un numero y requiero de un objeto json con todos los resultados por instrumento

Comment: Bueno aunque ya obteniendo los valores por instrumento los capturo en variables y creo un json con los datos que obtengo

Comment: Exacto, tenes que hacer la suma para recorrerlos y obtener el numero, luego construís el objeto que desees y le depositas el valor ..

Comment: Favor si sirvió la solución marcarla como correcta dándole al visto al costado de la respuesta, sirve para la reputación de quién se toma el tiempo de contestar, así como para que otros sepan que es correcta la respuesta y puedan aprovecharla si buscan algo similar. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por participar en el foro

Comment: Siempre es un placer, quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Tengo una duda. A veces me devuelve un numero y a veces un objeto. Ambos me sirven pero requiero dejar definido por cual de los 2. Ej: "Cantidad por instrumento y ciudad:" esta operación me devuelve un objeto pero si le quito un parámetro por ej:  && "item.ciudad === 'Medellin'" ya me trae un valor

Comment: Lo descubrí sacando de la data la posición 0

Comment: bueno, pues lo validé con un operador ternario. data.filter() == 1 ? 1 : la consulta con el reducer. Súper

Comment: Excelente me alegra que hayas resuelto, quedo a las ordenes.